# Running old Java Programs

Tags: java, swing, ide, compilation

a few years back in college I wrote TONS of simple little java programs... I haven't used them in a while and I would like to go back and revist them. I believe I used Netbeans as my IDE (but i also could have used Eclipse... cant remember)..

anyways long story short.... I cant remember how to compile them and I cant open these as projects in any of my IDEs....

I've tried using `javac` and then `java` to run a few in the command line, however one specifically will not run and gives me this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

I know this is because I don't have a `public static void main` method in this program. I can't remember why I don't.... but here's in theory how it should work.... I have 3 program files:

- race.java
- bicyclePanel.java
- controlPanel.java

race extends `JApplet` and has a method `public void init()`.... which creates an instance of controlPanel class.... `controlPanel` class creates an instance of `bicyclePanel`  and so on and so forth....

my question is.. am I supposed to have a `main` method? How can I rebuild this into an IDE and run? It's been so many years I cant remember all the in's & outs of java :(

Comment: Sounds like you need to run it as an Applet within a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are supposed to have the `main` method if you plan on running it as a standalone Java application. In Eclipse you can use the Applet runner to run your applets directy as well. It's Run As -> Java Applet.

Comment: thank you sir... this did the trick! totally spaced on aloto f the applet stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up NetBeans or Eclipse and Import the Projects with existing sources. It will do most of the stuff. You may have to adjust the broken references.